# AndroidPlot styling and positioning

Tags: android, charts, position, styling, androidplot

I'm trying to accomplish that:
http://s11.postimg.org/4jfa3bpxf/graph.png,
and so far I have that:
http://s23.postimg.org/4tizcnqyj/current_graph.png 
(never mind the colors, it's to make it easier to identify the different components).

I had few questions:

- I'd like to move the range label, but it seems that myPlot.getRangeLabelWidget().position(<...>) is not moving them
- how can I make the gray area (between the white graph and the red border) disappear? I tried to play with all the margins / padding without success
- how to keep only 1 blue dotted line? (the middle one). I can play with the margin to make it disappear, but then the number 10.0 disappear too
- to remove the domain labels, is it better to set the label color to transparent, or make the widget invisible?

Thanks in advance!

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chart, container, false);

    plot = (XYPlot) view.findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot);

    Number[] series1Numbers = {3, 8, 5, 2, 7, 4};

    XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(
            Arrays.asList(series1Numbers),
            SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY,
            ""); 

    LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter();
    series1Format.setPointLabelFormatter(new PointLabelFormatter());
    series1Format.configure(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.xml.line_point_formatter_with_plf1);

    plot.addSeries(series1, series1Format);

    plot.getLegendWidget().setVisible(false); // remove legend

    plot.setRangeStep(XYStepMode.SUBDIVIDE, 3);
    plot.setDomainStep(XYStepMode.SUBDIVIDE, 1);

    plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainLabelPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainOriginLabelPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    plot.getGraphWidget().getBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getGridBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);

    plot.setRangeBottomMax(0);
    plot.setRangeTopMin(10);

    plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainGridLinePaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeGridLinePaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);

    plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeOriginLinePaint().setColor(Color.GREEN);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainOriginLinePaint().setColor(Color.YELLOW);

    plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeGridLinePaint().setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{6, 10}, 1));

    plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeOriginLabelPaint().setColor(Color.GREEN);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeLabelPaint().setColor(Color.RED);

    plot.getBorderPaint().setColor(Color.RED);

    plot.setPlotMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    plot.setPlotPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

    plot.getGraphWidget().position(
            0, XLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_LEFT,
            0, YLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_TOP,
            AnchorPosition.LEFT_TOP);

    plot.getRangeLabelWidget().position(
            50, XLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_LEFT,
            50, YLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_TOP,
            AnchorPosition.LEFT_TOP);

    //plot.redraw();

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working with android plot right now as well, and also having some stoppers while working with it. But I will answer you partially based on what I accomplished.

- What do you mean by moving range label? to move it to the right of y-axis?
- To remove grey area you may use this code:

  `//space for all space

  // FILL mode with values of 0 means fill 100% of container:

  SizeMetrics sm = new SizeMetrics(0, SizeLayoutType.FILL, 0, SizeLayoutType.FILL);

  plot.getGraphWidget().setSize(sm);`
- Do you want to have only one Y gridline at all or just to hide the top one? What if you have more than 3 lines?
- I'd better make labels widget invisible/gone.

Comment: Turns out I implemented my own graph library because I only needed few elements.